Data Coordinator fails to start. Stuck in "Initializing"
I've got a bunch of logs that look like this
[2024/07/01 17:42:53.684 +00:00] [WARN] [datacoord/index_service.go:849] ["DataCoord 12139 is not ready"] [traceID=1a56c8bd789bd9dde94e8fdee0e927c1] [collectionID=448339039224594620] [error="service not ready[datacoord=12139]: Initializing"]
[2024/07/01 17:42:53.746 +00:00] [INFO] [datacoord/services.go:797] ["get recovery info request received"] [traceID=9d4c0a04cc578a1abeba6a9bbe0fbccb] [collectionID=448339039224915395] [partitionIDs="[]"]
[2024/07/01 17:42:53.746 +00:00] [INFO] [datacoord/services.go:797] ["get recovery info request received"] [traceID=ff858e069b81baa6cfbad28caa1e28fe] [collectionID=448339039243990697] [partitionIDs="[]"]
[2024/07/01 17:42:53.746 +00:00] [INFO] [datacoord/services.go:797] ["get recovery info request received"] [traceID=3a528ee771464452f5479a8d290f5822] [collectionID=448339039224854911] [partitionIDs="[]"]

That basically repeat until the k8s deployment gives up waiting for ready and kills the pod.
I'm using milvus 2.3.10 with version 4.1.21 of the official helm chart.
I'm looking for any advice on debugging what's going on here and how I might try to recover, or at least learn more about the problem.  Logs from the other components look relatively normal, best I can tell.
Thanks!

The troubleshooting steps are as follows:

Check the dependencies of Milvus, such as etcd, the message queue (Pulsar/Kafka), and object storage, to ensure they are working properly.
Check whether rootcoord is functioning normally.

You can use the script from https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/master/deployments/export-log/export-milvus-log.sh to upload logs to us.
